# Parsing PPTX in PHP, Need to find coordinates to attached images

Tags: php, google-slides

I am trying to get the X,Y coordinates of images uploaded to the PPTX file uploaded using PHP.
We are on a shared server, so limited by module usage.

There is no place where i could find anything. I tried searching the community, but unable to find a solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function pptx_extract_images() {
    // Getting post data
    $data = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
    $attachment_id = $data['attachment_id'];

    // Getting attachment file and  its name
    $input_file = get_attached_file($attachment_id);
    $input_file_name = pathinfo($input_file)["filename"];

    // Getting attachment type
    $attachment_type = pathinfo($input_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Making a zip archive package for pptx
    $package = new \ZipArchive();

    //if not a zip/pptx file
    if (!isset($package)) {
        return;
    }

    $package->open($input_file);

    // Read relations and search for images
    $relationsXml = $package->getFromName('_rels/.rels');

    if ($relationsXml === false) {
        $logger->write_log('pptx_extract_images', $relationsXml, 'Invalid archive or corrupted .pptx file.');
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid archive or corrupted .pptx file.');
    }

    $relations = simplexml_load_string($relationsXml);

    function absoluteZipPath($path) {
        $path = str_replace(array('/', '\\'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
        $parts = array_filter(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path), 'strlen');

        $absolutes = array();

        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            if ('.' == $part) continue;

            if ('..' == $part) {
                array_pop($absolutes);
            } else {
                $absolutes[] = $part;
            }
        }

        return implode('/', $absolutes);
    }

    // Document data holders
    $slides = 0;
    $data = array();

    foreach ($relations->Relationship as $rel) {
        if ($rel["Type"] == 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument') {

            $slideRelations = simplexml_load_string($package->getFromName(absoluteZipPath(dirname($rel["Target"]) . "/_rels/" . basename($rel["Target"]) . ".rels")));

            foreach ($slideRelations->Relationship as $slideRel) {
                if ($slideRel["Type"] == 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/slide') {

                    $slideNotesRelations = simplexml_load_string($package->getFromName(absoluteZipPath(dirname($rel["Target"]) . "/" . dirname($slideRel["Target"]) . "/_rels/" . basename($slideRel["Target"]) . ".rels")));

                    $slideNo = isset($slideRel["Target"]) ? str_replace('slide', '', pathinfo($slideRel["Target"])["filename"]) : null;

                    foreach ($slideNotesRelations->Relationship as $slideImageRel) {
                        if ($slideImageRel["Type"] == 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image') {

                            $image = basename($slideImageRel["Target"]);
                            $image_mime = explode('.', $image);

                            $count_explode = count($image_mime);
                            $image_mime = strtolower($image_mime[$count_explode - 1]);

                            if ($image_mime == 'gif') {
                                $data['page_' . ($slideNo - 1)]['animated_image'] = $attachment_id  . '-' .  $input_file_name . '/image-' . $image;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $slides++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $package->close();
}
```

Thanks for looking into it, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using the [PHPPresentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation) library. I note you mentioned difficulty with having modules, but that should not be an issue here as you can download the releases and `require` them (no need for composer). While the PHPPresentation documentation is a bit lacking, their examples are really good to help figure out how things work.

Here is what the pptx looks like:

[image: A series of images in a PowerPoint file]

The code:

```
<?php

/*

Question Author: Ali Hussain
Question Answerer: Jacob Mulquin
Question: Parsing PPTX in PHP, Need to find coordinates to attached images
URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76454701/parsing-pptx-in-php-need-to-find-coordinates-to-attached-images
Tags: php, google-slides

*/

require_once 'PHPPresentation-1.0.0/src/PhpPresentation/Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Autoloader::register();
require_once 'Common-1.0.1/src/Common/Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\Common\Autoloader::register();

$file = 'images.pptx';

$pptReader = PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\IOFactory::createReader('PowerPoint2007');
$oPHPPresentation = $pptReader->load($file);

function getShapeDetails($shape, $slide_number)
{
    $width = $shape->getWidth();
    $height = $shape->getHeight();

    if ($width === 0 || $height === 0) {
        return [];
    }

    $name = '';
    $description = '';

    if ($shape instanceof PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Shape\Drawing\Gd) {
        $name = $shape->getName();
        $description = $shape->getDescription();
    }

    return [
        'slide_number' => $slide_number+1,
        'hashcode' => $shape->getHashCode(),
        'offsetX' => $shape->getOffsetX(),
        'offsetY' => $shape->getOffsetY(),
        'width' => $width,
        'height' => $height,
        'name' => $name,
        'description' => $description
    ];
}

$images = [];
foreach ($oPHPPresentation->getAllSlides() as $slide_number => $oSlide) {
    foreach ($oSlide->getShapeCollection() as $oShape) {
        if ($oShape instanceof PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Shape\Group) {
            foreach ($oShape->getShapeCollection() as $oShapeChild) {
                $images[] = getShapeDetails($oShapeChild, $slide_number);
            }
        } else {
            $images[] = getShapeDetails($oShape, $slide_number);
        }
    }
}

// remove shapes that probably aren't images
$images = array_values(array_filter($images));

var_dump($images);
```

Yields:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["slide_number"]=>
    int(1)
    ["hashcode"]=>
    string(32) "e2b4ed359604645d2e483f037ef81b55"
    ["offsetX"]=>
    int(53)
    ["offsetY"]=>
    int(19)
    ["width"]=>
    int(468)
    ["height"]=>
    int(236)
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Picture 4"
    ["description"]=>
    string(89) "A picture containing smile, yellow, smiley, emoticon

Description automatically generated"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["slide_number"]=>
    int(1)
    ["hashcode"]=>
    string(32) "6ea656b2a8426a6d6f2393391056842f"
    ["offsetX"]=>
    int(925)
    ["offsetY"]=>
    int(148)
    ["width"]=>
    int(225)
    ["height"]=>
    int(225)
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Picture 6"
    ["description"]=>
    string(83) "A picture containing design, font, logo, white

Description automatically generated"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["slide_number"]=>
    int(2)
    ["hashcode"]=>
    string(32) "3ddc522c60417b61b8a5f316b0f29dc2"
    ["offsetX"]=>
    int(363)
    ["offsetY"]=>
    int(235)
    ["width"]=>
    int(402)
    ["height"]=>
    int(269)
    ["name"]=>
    string(21) "Content Placeholder 6"
    ["description"]=>
    string(102) "A group of men playing baseball in a field

Description automatically generated with medium confidence"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(8) {
    ["slide_number"]=>
    int(3)
    ["hashcode"]=>
    string(32) "cbefccdfc4db5e355f96bdc8d294296e"
    ["offsetX"]=>
    int(365)
    ["offsetY"]=>
    int(245)
    ["width"]=>
    int(870)
    ["height"]=>
    int(457)
    ["name"]=>
    string(21) "Content Placeholder 4"
    ["description"]=>
    string(90) "A picture containing text, font, screenshot, graphics

Description automatically generated"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I am sure i can get multiple other things like mime type, name etc and work my way to a solution. Much appreciated.

Comment: You absolutely can get that kind of info! I adapted this code from the `samples/Sample_Header.php` file which is in the PHPPresentation folder

Comment: The solution is indeed great, been trying to implement but breaks down in hosting when the file size increases. I wish there was a way to load the file in increments or parts.